# mayavi surf() how do I show colorbar?

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I can not figure out how to get the colorbar to show. I don't have much experience using mayavi, so I'm not sure what steps I need to to take to be able to figure this out?

Anyone else have similar problems
My code is shown below:

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np 
from mayavi import mlab

#getting the data from a txt file 
filename = askopenfilename()
type(filename) 
fileAsStr =''
data = []
count= 0
atData=False
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Note"):
            title = line
            title = title.strip("Note:")
            title = title.strip()
            print title
        if atData and not line.startswith('Total'):  #after the second one begin reading file
            line = line.replace(' ','')
            #data.append(line)
            fileAsStr = fileAsStr + line
        if line.startswith('-----'):
            count = count +1
        if count == 2:
            atData = True
dataStrIO = StringIO(fileAsStr)
dataArray = np.loadtxt(dataStrIO, delimiter=',')
dataDim = dataArray.shape
dx = dataArray[0:dataDim[0], 3]
dy = dataArray[0:dataDim[0], 4]
dz = dataArray[0:dataDim[0], 5]
bTotal = dataArray[0:dataDim[0],9]
firstNum = dy[0]
count = 0
while firstNum == dy[count]:
    count = count + 1
print 'count=' + str(count)

#arranging the arrays into an acceptable format
from itertools import islice
def solve(lis, n):
    it = iter(lis)
    return [list(islice(it,n)) for _ in xrange(len(lis)/n)] 
dx = np.transpose(solve(dx, count))
dy = np.transpose(solve(dy, count))
dz = solve(dz, count)
bTotal = solve(bTotal, count)
bTotal = np.log10(bTotal)


#making the plot
mlab.options.backend = 'envisage'
surf = mlab.surf(dx,dy, bTotal,warp_scale=2)

mlab.axes(surf, x_axis_visibility= True, y_axis_visibility = True, 
    z_axis_visibility = True, xlabel='x axis (mm)', ylabel='y axis (mm)', 
    zlabel ='z axis (mm)', nb_labels=10)

mlab.axes.label_text_property.font_size = 5 
mlab.title(title, line_width = .5, height = 1)
mlab.colorbar( title = "magnetic field (Tesla)")
```

Comment: What colors do you expect the colorbar to show? According to the `mlab.colorbar` docstring: If no object is specified, the first object with a colormap in the scene will be used. Here you don't have any objects with a colormap -- or rather, they use the default colormap but have no specified scalars.

Comment: The colormap isn't showing up on the graph.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem in general. I am also not able to run your code since I don't have your data files. Can you provide a minimal working example that does not depend on your data which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing an `mlab.show()` command at the end of your script.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.